# Converting JSON Data to Array / Extracting specific node in .NET

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

I have a JSON data, using NewtonSoft JSON library, I'm unable to extract the specific node (the coordinates) to an array, or to a list.

Here is my JSON Data:

```
{
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     [
                        28.9574884865954,
                        40.262043212854
                     ],
                     [
                        28.9577391646903,
                        40.2620393471008
                     ],
                     [
                        28.9581300766863,
                        40.2620333177299
                     ],
                     [
                        28.9581449735233,
                        40.261331625691
                     ],
                     [
                        28.9575062426388,
                        40.2613229341457
                     ],
                     [
                        28.9574884865954,
                        40.262043212854
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "ParselNo":"3",
            "SayfaNo":"6966",
            "Alan":"4.300,00",
            "Mevkii":"",
            "Nitelik":"Arsa",
            "CiltNo":"70",
            "Ada":"513",
            "Il":"Bursa",
            "Ilce":"Osmangazi",
            "Pafta":"H21b25d4b",
            "Mahalle":"Emek"
         }
      }
   ],
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"EPSG:4326"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure whether I have to use the JsonConvert class or JsonParse class.

I "only" want to extract the "coordinates" node including the lat/long values to a well-defined form like an array or to a list in C# or VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *first* thing you should always do when parsing JSON is go to http://json2csharp.com and have it generate the classes for you. In your case those classes are:

```
public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string ParselNo { get; set; }
    public string SayfaNo { get; set; }
    public string Alan { get; set; }
    public string Mevkii { get; set; }
    public string Nitelik { get; set; }
    public string CiltNo { get; set; }
    public string Ada { get; set; }
    public string Il { get; set; }
    public string Ilce { get; set; }
    public string Pafta { get; set; }
    public string Mahalle { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Crs
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties2 properties { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Crs crs { get; set; }
}
```

You can now deserialize using JSON.NET:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

At this point you've got an instance of RootObject. Grab whatever property value(s) you want.

**EDIT**

If you want the coordinates the first thing you have to note (by studying the classes I posted above, is that `coordinates` belong to the `Geometry` class. An instance of the `Geometry`class is in the `Feature` class and the `RootObject` class contains a `List<Feature>`. So to get to `coordinates` you need to loop over the `features` and extract the `coordinates` from each one.

```
foreach(var feature in root.features)
{
    var coordinatesForFeature = feature.geometry.coordinates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however i'm stuck here:  

var json_coord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Geometry>(jsontexthere);
json_coord.coordinates...?

Note that i want to get coordinates :(

Comment: Note that, json_coord variable refers to "Geometry" parent to identify "Coordinates" (not root). Please help :(

Comment: You cannot deserialize directly into `Geometry`. Did you not read the code I posted (i.e. the *exact* line of code you need to use to deserialize)? You *must* deserialize into `RootObject` and then get the bits you need from there. Coordinates is stored in `Feature` and `RootObject` contains a `List<Feature>` so you'll need to loop over that list to get all the coordinates.

Comment: Yes, i did read the code, and now i got it. I did the same what you said, thanks again. I looped over the List<Feature> than indexed the sub-elements to get Coordinates. Thanks again!